# How do I weed out different parts of a single String while having the result be a String itself?

Tags: java, string, methods, char

So I'm supposed to write a Java method that weeds out the unwanted spaces from a sentence and keeps the numbers/letter (i in this case). For example, if you have "      0  .  2    -    9. 3   i", you should end up with o.2-9.3i and if you have "- 1  .  6 +   8. 3i" you should end up with -1.6+8.3i (nothing comes after i for all cases, just to be clear). We were given a hint to use the javadocs for both String and Double (for the double part, you can use the parseDouble method to achieve the final answers.) Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like your supposed to test each token i its a number only then remove spaces?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but what would the method return at the end? That's where I got stuck.

Comment: i just saw your example again, looks like what people have posted below is fine. see   
Andrew Carlson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is what you are looking for.

```
" 0 . 2 - 9. 3 i".replace(" ", "");
```

if you need it as a method:

```
public string removeSpaces(String subject) {
    return subject.replace(" ", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`st.replaceAll("\\s","")` removes all whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

`st.replaceAll("\\s","")`  ... will get rid of white spaces

Comment: @AndrewCarlson- `\s` replaces all whitespace characters including newline, but the user is asking only to remove/ replace space .. that's what I meant.